# How to use a python package with sudo privileges inside Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, sudo

I have a Flask setup in my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B via [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial.

OS = Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS

Python = 3.8

Please keep in mind that I am using virtual env for my Flask application as shown in the tutorial and my Flask application is running absolutely fine.

Now I installed `Adafruit_DHT` in the same venv and tried using the following code in one of the endpoints

```
import Adafruit_DHT
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 24)
```

to which I am getting the following error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 81, in read
    return platform.read(sensor, pin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT/Raspberry_Pi_2.py", line 34, in read
    raise RuntimeError('Error accessing GPIO.')
RuntimeError: Error accessing GPIO.
```

So, after that, I created a simple python script say `z.py` and wrote the above code in it. Then, I activated the same Flask venv using

```
source venv1/bin/activate
```

And run the script using

```
python z.py
```

Again I got the same error. But If I run the above command as sudo

```
sudo python z.py
```

then script executed perfectly fine and I got the following response

```
87.0999984741211 29.399999618530273
```

So, now the question arrives, how do I use `Adafruit_DHT` package inside the Flask app with sudo permission?

I don't think setting `777` to `www-data` group would be the right choice. Or running the Flask app as `sudo` user would be a great idea.

I have tried installing `Adafruit_DHT` package globally with `sudo`, but still I have to execute `z.py` as `sudo`

So what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the package will be trying to access the device /dev/gpiomem (possibly (/dev/gpiochip0 or /dev/gpiochip1).

I think the neatest way to address this would be have those devices be owned by a group other than root and give that group permission to access the device, e.g.

```
sudo su
groupadd gpio
chgrp gpio /dev/gpio*
chmod g+rw /dev/gpio*
```

Then I'd go ahead and add your user to that group (by default this is ubuntu, but you may have created another user):

```
usermod -a -G gpio ubuntu
```

Now you've created a group called "gpio" that now has permissions to access your Pi's GPIO, and added your user to that group.

Please note, I have not tested this

Comment: this is working fine. there is just one issue I am facing, that, when I reboot raspberry pi, chgrp is lost, means, /dev/gpio* are reset to root root. I have to again execute two commands i.e., chgrp and chmod. any idea how to fix it, or have I done something wrong?

Comment: So the technically correct option is probably to write a systemd/udev rule, or init script. However, they are very powerful tools and that will necessitate a fair bit of work to achieve this quite simple goal.  Instead, I'd add a crontab rule that should do just the same:
```
sudo su
crontab -e

then in there:
@reboot chgrp gpio /dev/gpio*
@reboot chmod g+rw /dev/gpio*

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I saw udev rules, and they require some work. Thanks for the crontab sugeestion. Its clean and simple.